# Check-and-Set (CAS) operations with Booksleeve and Redis

Tags: database, redis, booksleeve

Does Booksleeve support CAS operations (i.e. the Redis [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch) command)? For example, how would one implement something like the following?

```
WATCH mykey
val = GET mykey
val = val + 1
MULTI
SET mykey $val
EXEC
```

I would need this to avoid race conditions when multiple threads try to modify the same object with the same data.

Comment: This has now changed, and is now implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>In nuget currently, I don't think so. For the reason that BookSleeve is *usually* intended to be used as a multiplexer, which makes "watch" unusable. I could *add* it, bit you would have to limit usage to a single caller (per BookSleeve connection) for the duration of your operation.</s>

This [has now changed](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/multiplexed-transactions-in-booksleeve.html); if we wanted to manually implement `INCR` (as per your example) we could use:

```
// note this could be null if the old key didn't exist
var oldVal = await connection.Strings.GetInt64(db, key);

var newVal = (oldVal ?? 0) + 1;
using (var tran = connection.CreateTransaction())
{
    // check hasn't changed (this handles the WATCH, a checked GET,
    // and an UNWATCH if necessary); note tat conditions are not sent
    // until the Execute is called
    tran.AddCondition(Condition.KeyEquals(db, key, oldVal));

    // apply changes to perform assuming the conditions succeed
    tran.Strings.Set(db, key, newVal); // the SET

    // note that Execute includes the MULTI/EXEC, assuming the conditions pass
    if (!await tran.Execute()) return null; // aborted; either a pre-condition
                                         // failed, or a WATCH-key was changed
    return newVal; // successfully incremented
}
```

obviously you might want to execute that in a repeated (within sane limits) loop so that if it is aborted because of the `WATCH`, you redo from the start.

This is *slightly* different to your example, as it actually does (assuming the value wasn't changed between the initial `GET` and the second `GET`):

```
val = GET mykey
newval = (val ?? 0) + 1
WATCH mykey
chk = GET mykey // and verifies chk == val as part of the Execute
MULTI
SET mykey $newval
EXEC
```

noting that the `EXEC` can still report cancellation if the value was changed between the `WATCH` and the `EXEC`; or (if it *has* changed between the two `GET`s):

```
val = GET mykey
newval = (val ?? 0) + 1
WATCH mykey
chk = GET mykey // and verifies chk == val as part of the Execute
UNWATCH
```

The difference is one more `GET`, but that is the only way it can work with a multiplexer - i.e. so that the `Execute` is optimized to be reliably fast, so that it doesn't impact other callers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering because AppHarbor can fire up multiple instances of my background application (which has Quartz doing scheduling that should only once within a certain time frame) and I wanted to guarantee that each scheduled operation happens only once. I had planned to insert a value into a list and guarantee that it is the only one while it is there. Is there any work around?

Comment: @tamaslnagy well, the code in the question: is that anything that couldn't be done with "incr" ? Which is atomic automatically? There is also some distributed-lock code built in ow which *uses* "watch", but it does it by blocking the multiplexer for a brief moment. If the scenario fits, you could try using that code?

Comment: What is ow? If inc is atomic then that might be suitable. Is remove atomic?

Comment: @tamaslnagy "ow" is a typo of "now" ;p Yes, remove is atomic. For the locking stuff, see `.Strings.TakeLock(...)`, which does either `WATCH`, `EXISTS`, `UNWATCH` - or `WATCH`, `EXISTS`, `MULTI`, `SETNX`, `EXPIRE`,  `EXEC` depending on whether it looks available

Comment: That looks like it could work. I would just TakeLock on a key until I decide to ReleaseLock or the lock expires? Oh, and fyi Booksleeve is a really awesome tool; just in case you didn't know :P

Comment: @tamaslnagy yes, the TakeLock / ReleaseLock should do the job. Try to leave plenty of time so it won't expire during normal execution.

Comment: Hmmm. I saw that ReleaseLock says this "You should not release a lock that you did not take, as this will cause problems." I have competing threads and I might release lock in a thread but the other thread would not know this and will attempt to release the lock again. Would this give me errors?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem. I am curious to know why ReleaseLock() doesn't return the value stored using TakeLock()

Comment: @tamaslnagy hmmm, I guess it could. My assumption there is that you **wouldn't call it** unless it was you that took the lock, in which case you would already know the value - however, the value would be available for cross-check by *unsuccessful takers*, i.e. "this record is currently locked by tamasInagy" - but you make a fair point. I might add that.

Comment: It would be nice if it WATCH/UNWATCH was implemented but i guess i could escape key names and use a global mutex or the lock as you suggested. +1. I'm going to stick with mutex because if i leave the function its auto release/unwatch and i wont have to call ReleaseLock in redis

Comment: @acidzombie24 I'll probably add those in due course, but it has to be stressed that using them **breaks the multiplexer** - so: don't multiplex with that ;p In fact, I'll probably find some way of making it a mutex

Comment: What do you mean by 'break'? I don't see any performance warnings (which wont matter if i need correctness) and afaik it doesnt matter if other threads write to the connection as long as that function does watch and its gets/multi in the order it sent it out everything should be fine?

Comment: If your curious why i may want watch/unwatch it would be for the UVComment function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221882/how-would-so-post-be-written-with-redis or maybe UpdatePost